# Retrieving number value from input instead of object

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I am trying to write a small program to determine the common factors between two numbers. I am having a problem getting the numbers, though. Here is my HTML code:

```
<p>Please input two numbers to find the common factors between them.</p>
 First number:<input type="number" id="firstNumber"></br>
 Second number:<input type="number" id="secondNumber"></br>
<button onclick="commonFactors(document.getElementById('firstNumber'), 
 document.getElementById('secondNumber'))">Submit</button>
```

However, instead of getting the numbers back, the console returns the following:

```
"<input type='number' id='firstNumber'>" "<input type='number' 
  id='secondNumber'>"
```

With the quotes. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Not sure it matters, but here's the JS:

```
function commonFactors(num1, num2) {
  console.log(num1, num2);
  var counter=Math.min(num1, num2);
  var factors=[];
  var k=0;  
  for (i=1; i<counter; i++) {
    if (num1%i==0) {
      if (num2%i==0) {
        factors[k]=i;
      }
    }
    k+=1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

because `document.getElementById('firstNumber')` is refering to the input, use `+document.getElementById('firstNumber').value` notice the `+` because the values you get from an input are of type `string` so we use the `+` to transform them to a number

Note: you can use a function instead of the `+` it's called `parseInt()` for integers and `parseFloat()` for float numbers

the result is

```
    <button onclick="commonFactors(parseInt(document.getElementById('firstNumber').value), 
 parseInt(document.getElementById('secondNumbe').value)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you! It took a combination of both parseInt and .value to work.

Comment: yeah, you'll need both of them as stated in the first paragraph. I forgot to add .value in the example

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the value of the input, not the input itself :

> document.getElementById('firstNumber').value

Comment: Thanks! See above comment.